# get_next_posts_page_link adds Inexistent directories

Tags: pagination

Using get_next_posts_page_link function to get url of paginated post's next page url, but it's adding directories to it that simply do not exist.

Here is the code where I use it and probably missing something somewhere

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        the_content();
endwhile;
// echoing to see the actual url it would bring up if used in an anchor
echo get_next_posts_page_link();
```

And here are the urls

**On page 1:**
mysitedomain.com/paginatedpage/page/2/
*instead of* 
mysitedomain.com/paginatedpage/2/

**On page 2:**
mysitedomain.com/paginatedpage/2/page/2/
*instead of* 
mysitedomain.com/paginatedpage/3/

**On page 3:**
mysitedomain.com/paginatedpage/3/page/2/
*instead of* 
mysitedomain.com/paginatedpage/4/

And so on...

Comment: in what file are you using that function?

Comment: custom page template

Comment: Archive pagination is `/page/n/`, singular post/page pagination is `/n/`. You say this is on a custom page template, which would indicate that this is a *singular* view and not an archive view, but your loop seems to indicate otherwise. Clarification is required here.

Comment: I'm talking about paginating by <!--nextpage-->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want links to the next and previous pages on a singular page created with `<!--nextpage-->` then you're using the wrong function.

`get_next_posts_page_link()`, as suggested by the name, is for getting the next page *of posts* and is intended for use on archives.

To add the pagination links to a singular page, use [`wp_link_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/), and use it inside the loop.

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content();

    wp_link_pages();
endwhile;
```

By default it outputs page numbers, but if you want "Next" and "Previous" links, set the `next_or_number` argument to `next`:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content();

    wp_link_pages( array(
        'next_or_number' => 'next',
    ) );
endwhile;
```

See [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/) for more options for customising the output.

Comment: what if i need an actual url to use in an anchor to add inline onclick script?

Comment: There isn't a function for that. Does the script *need* to be inline?

Comment: Ideally- yes, to make sure it's loaded by the time other elements connected to it are loaded. But I guess I can hide the link till document is ready. Thanks!